# Schema `boxfuse-dev-db` contains a failed migration to version 10 ! The migration works locally but not in production nor on dev

Tags: flyway, cloudcaptain

I'm working on a web app that uses Springboot, Boxfuse and Flyway.
I created the following migration:

V10__UpdateProperty.sql

which contains the following:

```
ALTER TABLE property MODIFY COLUMN long_description TEXT DEFAULT '';
```

And added the @Lob annotation to the Java property longDescription:

```
@Entity
public class Property {
    private @Lob String longDescription; 

   // Other properties and getters and setters

}
```

When I run the app locally it works.
But when I run the boxfuse command:

```
boxfuse run -env=prod
```

It fails.... I get the following error:

(Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Schema `boxfuse-dev-db` contains a failed migration to version 10 !)

```
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:21.747  :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.2.RELEASE)
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:21.747
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:21.904 2017-06-21 16:04:21.900  INFO 713 --- [           main] co.easymatch.Em2Application              : Starting Em2Application v0.7.12 on vb-18d089ff with PID 713 (/app/em2-0.7.12.jar started by root in /app)
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:21.904 2017-06-21 16:04:21.904  INFO 713 --- [           main] co.easymatch.Em2Application              : The following profiles are active: boxfuse
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:22.123 2017-06-21 16:04:22.123  INFO 713 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2077d4de: startup date [Wed Jun 21 16:04:22 GMT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:27.930 2017-06-21 16:04:27.930  INFO 713 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'scopedTarget.oauth2ClientContext' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=session; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=false; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2ClientContextConfiguration; factoryMethodName=oauth2ClientContext; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2ClientContextConfiguration] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=session; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=false; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestOperationsConfiguration$SessionScopedConfiguration$ClientContextConfiguration; factoryMethodName=oauth2ClientContext; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2RestOperationsConfiguration$SessionScopedConfiguration$ClientContextConfiguration.class]]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:27.934 2017-06-21 16:04:27.934  INFO 713 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'oauth2ClientFilterRegistration' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=em2Application; factoryMethodName=oauth2ClientFilterRegistration; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in co.easymatch.Em2Application] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestOperationsConfiguration$SessionScopedConfiguration; factoryMethodName=oauth2ClientFilterRegistration; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2RestOperationsConfiguration$SessionScopedConfiguration.class]]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:28.046 2017-06-21 16:04:28.046  INFO 713 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'ignoredPathsWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration; factoryMethodName=ignoredPathsWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=ignoredPathsWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class]]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:28.353 2017-06-21 16:04:28.352  INFO 713 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'managementServletContext' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcHypermediaManagementContextConfiguration; factoryMethodName=managementServletContext; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcHypermediaManagementContextConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=managementServletContext; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:31.055 2017-06-21 16:04:31.034  INFO 713 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:31.321 2017-06-21 16:04:31.319  INFO 713 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7419792e] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:32.408 2017-06-21 16:04:32.407  INFO 713 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:32.425 2017-06-21 16:04:32.425  INFO 713 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:32.426 2017-06-21 16:04:32.426  INFO 713 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.6
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:32.593 2017-06-21 16:04:32.592  INFO 713 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:32.593 2017-06-21 16:04:32.592  INFO 713 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 10471 ms
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:33.349 2017-06-21 16:04:33.334  WARN 713 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.b.d.a.RemoteDevToolsAutoConfiguration : Listening for remote debug traffic on /.~~spring-boot!~/debug
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:33.380 2017-06-21 16:04:33.380  WARN 713 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.b.d.a.RemoteDevToolsAutoConfiguration : Listening for remote restart updates on /.~~spring-boot!~/restart
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:33.437 2017-06-21 16:04:33.434  INFO 713 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'metricsFilter' to: [/*]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:33.437 2017-06-21 16:04:33.434  INFO 713 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:33.437 2017-06-21 16:04:33.434  INFO 713 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:33.437 2017-06-21 16:04:33.434  INFO 713 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:33.437 2017-06-21 16:04:33.434  INFO 713 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'OAuth2ClientContextFilter' to: [/*]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:33.437 2017-06-21 16:04:33.434  INFO 713 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:33.437 2017-06-21 16:04:33.436  INFO 713 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:33.437 2017-06-21 16:04:33.436  INFO 713 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'webRequestLoggingFilter' to: [/*]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:33.437 2017-06-21 16:04:33.436  INFO 713 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:33.437 2017-06-21 16:04:33.436  INFO 713 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'remoteDevToolsDispatcherFilter' to: [/*]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:33.437 2017-06-21 16:04:33.436  INFO 713 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:33.440 2017-06-21 16:04:33.437  INFO 713 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'webServlet' to [/h2-console/*]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:33.934 2017-06-21 16:04:33.934  INFO 713 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.util.VersionPrinter    : Flyway 3.2.1 by Boxfuse
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.266 2017-06-21 16:04:34.266  INFO 713 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.dbsupport.DbSupportFactory       : Database: jdbc:mysql://10.0.2.2:3306/boxfuse-dev-db (MySQL 5.6)
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.807 2017-06-21 16:04:34.807  INFO 713 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Current version of schema `boxfuse-dev-db`: 10
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.810 2017-06-21 16:04:34.810  WARN 713 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Schema `boxfuse-dev-db` contains a failed migration to version 10 !
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.819 2017-06-21 16:04:34.819  INFO 713 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.834 2017-06-21 16:04:34.834  WARN 713 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available)
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841 2017-06-21 16:04:34.840 ERROR 713 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Schema `boxfuse-dev-db` contains a failed migration to version 10 !
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at co.easymatch.Em2Application.main(Em2Application.java:44) [classes!/:0.7.12]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0-8u131]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0-8u131]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0-8u131]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0-8u131]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [em2-0.7.12.jar:0.7.12]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [em2-0.7.12.jar:0.7.12]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [em2-0.7.12.jar:0.7.12]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58) [em2-0.7.12.jar:0.7.12]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841 Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Schema `boxfuse-dev-db` contains a failed migration to version 10 !
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$2.doInTransaction(DbMigrate.java:196) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar!/:na]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$2.doInTransaction(DbMigrate.java:156) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar!/:na]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:72) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar!/:na]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.migrate(DbMigrate.java:156) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar!/:na]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1059) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar!/:na]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1006) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar!/:na]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1418) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar!/:na]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:1006) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar!/:na]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
vb-18d089ff => 2017-06-21 17:04:34.841  ... 26 common frames omitted
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with the migration.

I even tried using

```
ALTER TABLE property DROP COLUMN long_description;
ALTER TABLE property ADD long_description TEXT DEFAULT '';
```

But the same error happens.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The migration is marked as failed in the `schema_version` table. You have to issue a `Flyway.repair()` to fix it. ALternatively you can also drop the database with `Flyway.clean()` and let it recreate it on the next call to `Flyway.migrate()`.

Answer (score 1):

Show all the Flyway data migration by

```
SELECT * FROM schema_version;
```

Then delete the failed migration by

```
DELETE FROM schema_version WHERE version = '10';
```