# flyway exception, detected failed migration

Tags: database, flyway

I've got a Flyway exception:

```
FlywayException: Detected failed migration to version 1.0
```

I looked for on documentation and forums but I didn't found what mean this exception.
Please someone can tell me what can be the reasons of these exception !
Thanks

Comment: Look at this fix 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44681583/schema-boxfuse-dev-db-contains-a-failed-migration-to-version-10-the-migratio/69347777#69347777

Answer (score 42):

> "FlywayException: Detected failed migration to version 1.0"

it means that you ran migrate before and it failed at 1.0 for some reason. You need to identify why the previous migration failed at 1.0 and solve it if you have already not done so.
Once solved you need to run `flyway repair` to tell flyway that whatever failed is now out of the way.

Then run `flyway migrate` again. If it fails again, you are back on step 1.
Good luck with the migration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...i finally found a basic sql error in my code...i ran  again flyway as you said...and it works :)

Comment: Saved my day !!

Comment: "flyway repair", my understanding is that it removed the 'failed' from schema history table.  Yet part of the failed migration might already run. I had to find the line of error, comment out all lines above since they 're done, then run "flyway migrate" again, works perfectly.

Comment: How to execute flyway repair ?

Comment: `mvn flyway:repair` in console should do.
if using intelliJ you have this in maven plugins
`maven -> <service name> -> plugins -> flyway -> flyway:repair`

Answer (score 28):

Make

```
select * from your_database_name.flyway_schema_history
```

you will get something like this:

Query to flyway_schema_history table
[image: query to flyway_schema_history table]]

Then find the entry that corresponds to the migration that is failing and delete it, it should work.

Comment: Note, that this table might have a different name depending on the configuration