# Detected failed migration to version Flyway

Tags: sql, intellij-idea, database-migration, flyway

I added a sql file to my project and now I am receiving the following error:

> nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed: Detected failed migration to version 1.0.9 (update)

Here is my sql file I'm adding:

```
ALTER TABLE `episodes`
ADD COLUMN `rating` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

I added the same query to MySQL Workbench and it's working fine, so I think the error here is beyond the sql file added

UPDATE: full stack trace below

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed: Detected failed migration to version 1.0.9 (update)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1708)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243)
at com.nbcuni.cds.Application.main(Application.java:12)
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed: Detected failed migration to version 1.0.9 (update)
at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.doValidate(Flyway.java:1286)
at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.access$100(Flyway.java:71)
at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1176)
at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1168)
at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1655)
at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:1168)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1767)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1704)
... 18 common frames omitted
```

> UPDATE: When I run mvn:flyway-validate, I receive the following error:

```
org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to connect to the database. Configure the url, user and password!
```

> I'm not sure where to configure it? It's already set in my applications.properties file? And w/o this version the spring application is working fine

Comment: Is this the migration with version 1.0.9? What is the exact and complete stack trace of the exception? What does the table episodes look like?

Comment: @JBNizet see above. Is this what you're referring to?

Comment: Yes, that's a stack trace. Is the migration you're showing the migration with version 1.0.9? What does the table episodes look like?

Comment: @JBNizet  Columns:
uuid | varchar(36) PK
season_uuid | varchar(36)
title | varchar(255)
description | text

Comment: If that is really the migration which is failing (since you won't tell if that is the migration with version 1.9), my guess is that your table already has the rating column. Maybe because you tested the request before using MySQL Workbench.

Comment: @JBNizet sorry yes this is the migration with version 1.9, I dropped the column from MySQL Workbench after I tested it to make sure its a valid query, so currently there's no column in the episodes table named rating. I wanted to add it through this file but I keep getting this error

Comment: Check if it has really been deleted. Maybe you forgot to commit. Quit the workbench, start it again. Check that you're looking at the database/schema that the application is using, and not a different schema.

Comment: @JBNizet yes I have double checked, deleted the file and tried to create it again, and I keep getting the same error. I think the problem might be beyond the sql query?

Comment: Do you use "Flyway Migration Creation" plugin:  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8597-flyway-migration-creation ?

Comment: @y.bedrov no I don't. I didn't know a plugin existed. I was creating a new file in the package and giving it the sql extension.

Comment: Is it possible to share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE?

Comment: Look at this fix 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44681583/schema-boxfuse-dev-db-contains-a-failed-migration-to-version-10-the-migratio/69347777#69347777

Answer (score 4):

I guess the problem is the error in migration history saved on your database.
Try deleting the line that failed and try again. If the error won't vanish, the problem is somehow in your statement.

I just had the same issue :)

Comment: I have similar issue, even after deleting the database and creating new one, Flyway still complains about failed migration.

Comment: This is really bad. Perhaps a specific version of flyway will solve this. Basically it still migrates even though it fails. And you can't edit it because it's already versioned. Catch 22.

Answer (score 0):

below resolved the validate problem for me:

```
mvn flyway:validate -Dflyway.configFile=myFlywayConfig.properties
```

Comment: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unknown configuration property: flyway.configFile

Answer (score 0):

The error happen if there is any record is inserted into the 'flyway_schema_history' with failed status or part of the failed migration might already run. Just need to remove failed recored from the 'flyway_schema_history' then run "flyway migrate" again.

Query to flyway_schema_history table

```
select * from your_database_name.flyway_schema_history
```

You will get something like this:

[image]

Remove the record with success =0 and run again "flyway migrate".

Note, that this table might have a different name depending on the configuration